# How can I color in this picture?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shapes

[image]

I'm making this on adobe illustrator, it's one shape (minus the eyes) and several lines. How can I color the bottom half of the whale, not using the paintbrush tool?

Answer (score 1):

Select all

Grab the **Live Paint Bucket Tool**

Pick a color

start clicking

When done, click the `Expand` button on the Control Bar across the top of the screen.